# Ho can I rotate/scale animate the drawable in FloatingActionButton or ImageView

Tags: android, animation, rotation, android-animation, android-drawable

For, example I am having a floating action button and I want to animate the drawable part of it.

The Floating Action Button should not move or scale. Only the drawable part can scale and rotate.

For Example, [Here](https://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_4/material_ext_publish/0B6Okdz75tqQsdk1oMG9KY2pCcms/components-progressactivity-typesofindicators-Circular_wFab_xhdpi_003.mp4) the tick mark coming at the end is animating inside the FAB button. I just want to achive the scaling/rotating animation of the drawable inside the FAB, But FAB should not scale or rotate.

Rotation can't be a problem as a circular shape rotation is not visible if i rotate the full FAB with `RotateAnimation`. But scaling and rotating both can't be done with the fab, as it is seen the background of FAB is scaling.

**Note:** I don't want to rotate the full FAB button. ONLY the drawable part.

Answer (score 1):

for **scaling button** 
you can do like
in **anim** folder/

## scale_button.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<scale
     android:fromXScale="1.4"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.4"
    android:toYScale="1.0"
    android:fillAfter="false"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:interpolator="@anim/cycle" />
```

## cycle.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<cycleInterpolator 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:cycles="0" 
/>
```

## MainActivity.java

```
Animation shake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.shake);
your_view_name.startAnimation(shake);
```